# Making overleaf hyphenation ignore certain characters

Tags: hyphenation

I'm recently transcribing and editing a text, which includes the usage of some special characters. Sadly they mess with the hyphenation and impede syllable division. Is there any way to explicitly exclude those characters from overleaf's 'consideration' in regards of hyphenation, in the sense that `con|stansq[ue]` is treated as `con|\-stans\-q[ue]`, meaning with the same hyphenation as `constansque`. Inserting `\-` manually every time necessary is very time consuming and stultifying. (Allowing overleaf to break words after `|` would have the same result for me.) Thanks a lot, Maxi.

```
\documentclass[12pt, doublespacing]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek, dutch, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2cm, right=2cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

QVI res gestas litteris | consignare, atque ad | memoriam postero|rum transmittere primi cœpe|runt, illi mihi videntur \textsc{Devm} | æmulari voluisse, dum in nihi|lum relapsura præstatissima | quæq[ue] facinora retinere, \& suâ | quadam immortalitate dona|re studuerunt. Qui quidem | optimorum hominum labor | si vlla in re bene impensus est, || in eo certè vel optimè collo|catus esse censeri debet, si quæ | in \textsc{Dei}, Diuorumq[ue] honorem | præclarè gesta sunt, ea \& ab | obliuione vindicare, \& ven|turis ætatibus conservare sol|licitè laborarit. Sicut enim di|uino cultu nullum ab homine | opus proficisci potest excel|lentius, ita quod in eo ge|nere à nobis præstitum est lit|terarum tradere monumentis | perpetuus quidam DEI, con|stansq[ue] cultus est. …

\end{document}
```

Comment: overleaf hosts a standard texlive so isn't really involved here, hyphenation is the same wherever you ran TeX .I would define a command say `\renewcommand\|{|\linebreak[0]}` then use `\|`or  `\renewcommand\|{|\-}` if you want a hyphen if it breaks there

Comment: Off-topic: One could replace `left=2cm, right=2cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm` with the more succinct expression `hmargin=2cm, vmargin=3.5cm`.

Comment: Using Leiden conventions you might also have abc║ abc how do you want to handle the || then? I think is best to use \raggedright  with the Latin words unhyphenated and manually break the lines. Best also IMHO not to use the inline model, but rather the text should be reflected the way it is on the manuscript/papyrus/stone etc.

Answer (score 1):

overleaf hosts a standard texlive so isn't really involved here, hyphenation is the same wherever you ran TeX.

I would define a command, say

```
\renewcommand\|{|\linebreak[0]}
```

then use `\|`

Or use

```
\renewcommand\|{|\-}
```

if you want a hyphen if it breaks there.